# Access C++ class member object, but do not allow to override it

Tags: c++, class, pointers, vector, smart-pointers

I'm learning C++ and i just have a small problem. I have a class which contains a `vector<int>`. From outside this `vector<int>` should be accessable, so it should be possible to add/remove/get its elements.

It should not be possible to override the object with a new instance.
Here is such an example class (it's minimalized):

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        vector<int>& vec() { return _vec; }
    private:
        vector<int> _vec;
};
```

E.g. the following code works:

```
MyClass x;
x.vec().push_back(0);
x.vec().push_back(7);
x.vec().push_back(9);
cout << c.vec().size() << endl;
```

But unfortunately the following code also works:

```
MyClass x;
x.vec() = vector<int>();
```

I like to disallow this, but i did only find the solution to return a pointer of type `vector<int> *`. But i learned pointers are 'evil' and i shouldn't use them directly, i have to use smart pointers. I think for this problem a smart pointer is useless, so i don't know how to solve this simple problem:-/

Or is just a simple pointer the cleanest solution?

best regards

Kevin

-edit-

In general i like to make something that can be used like the follwing C# class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public List<int> List { get; private set; }

    public MyClass()
    {
        List = new List<int>();
    }
}
```

It's just an example and i just thought about how to make this in C++. Maybe i some cases i have much more complex classes than `vector<int>`/`List<int>` to include into other classes.

But maybe it is only possible to do this by defining own methods (=interface) to the internal object.

Comment: Don't return a reference, and add a special function to add values? Having a public function returning a reference to a member variable, is like having the member variable itself public.

Comment: Pointers aren't evil, but don't help here. You should hide the vector detail an provide the right interface to manipulate the data.

Comment: if you want to expose all the methods of the vector, don't see any harm in exposing the assignment operator as well (in this case you could also inherit public from vector what would be simpler). if you want to have control and allow only some operators to be public hide the vector and write your own proxy functions

Comment: Ok, i see this solution, but if a class contains a more complex object than `vector<int>` and i like to give others the full access to this object then it's much work to (re-)implement the internal objects interface to the current class. E.g. in C# it's very easy to do this: `class test{ public List<int> Lst { get; private set; } public test() { Lst = new List<int>(); } }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems wrong to me that the only acceptable solution is to provide forwarding functions for potentially all the methods in the vector class. So I would like to propose an alternative answer.

Create a small template class publically derived from `vector` that hides the `operator=` method by making it private.

```
template<class T>
class immutablevector : public vector<T>
{
  private:
    immutablevector &operator=(vector<T>);
};
```

Then in `MyClass`, wherever you would have used `vector`, use `immutablevector` instead.

```
class MyClass
{
  public:
    immutablevector<int>& vec() { return _vec; }
  private:
    immutablevector<int> _vec;
};
```

Now you can safely access all vector functionality via the `vec` method, but you won't be able to assign a new vector instance.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit strange how you use the `private` identifier. 
You set your `vector<int>` as `private` and then you create a public method that gives direct access to that variable.

You should instead create  public methods `get()` and `push_back()`

```
class MyClass{
     private: vector<int> _vec;
     public: 
         vector<int> get(){ return _vec(); }
         void push_back(int x) { _vec.push_back(x); }
};

//this will work
MyClass x;
x.push_back(0);
x.push_back(7);
x.push_back(9);
cout<<x.get().size()<<endl;
```

Now there is not way you to directly modify the `private` variable `vector<int> _vec`.
Keep in mind you will probably need to instantiate `_vec` in `MyClass`'s constructor.

Comment: The public method to the private member vector array is not such a bad thing. It allows, for example, to add logging anytime an item is added to the array, in just one place in the code.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't that defeat the purpose of `private` access specifier?

Comment: No, because you're forcing access to go through the accessor function, which means you wouldn't then be able to bypass the logging if you wanted access to the member.

Comment: Also, you might, for example, want to maintain a count of accesses to the object, which again means you want to force usage of the accessor function and keep the actual member private.

Comment: This is interesting. Never actually though of this. Thanks.

Comment: @Merlin069 I still consider it terrible design to expose `_vec` . I think dragos is completely correct. Just imagine that after a year or two in a collaborative environment you would really really like to switch to a different vector implementation. Ouch.-- Note that the cases you cite are mere debugging aides. And nothing keeps you from having a _protected_ accessor which all public functions must use (as a coding rule), so that you could still log all accesses.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to consider using functions to only expose the functionality you need:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void push_back(int value) { _vec.push_back(value); }
    size_t size() { return _vec.size(); }

private:
    vector<int> _vec;
};

int main()
{
    MyClass x;
    x.push_back(0);
    x.push_back(7);
    x.push_back(9);
    cout << x.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Or alternatively just use a plain vector.